# flip words in a list

Tags: python, string

I did the following:

```
mylist  = ['pencil', 'dog', 'memo', 'Hello']
```

I want to flip each individual word like:

```
['licnep', 'god', 'omem', 'olleH']
```

I've tried the following:

```
for word in mylist:
    word = word[::-1]
```

However, the above method doesn't work. Please explain.

Comment: `word` is reversed and then _not used_. You need to either put that back to the original list, or create a new list containing `word`s.

Comment: use comprehension - ```flipped = [word[::-1] for word in mylist]```

Comment: you were just missing the `print()` call to word. so like this  `print(word)` right after word and you would get the words in a flipped order.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should create a new list and append the flipped words in the new list.

Check the following code below:

```
mylist  = ['pencil', 'dog', 'memo', 'Hello']

newlist = []
for word in mylist:
    word = word[::-1]
    newlist.append(word)

print(newlist)
```

Your code did not work because - **For each iteration of the for loop, the variable `word` is assigned with just a copy of the value of an item in `mylist`, so changes made to word won't be reflected in `mylist`. Here `word` is just a local variable and it does not reference an item in `mylist`.**

Answer (score 1):

Actually, the above method is not making a change in the actual list.
Try this:-

```
[word[::-1] for word in mylist]
```

Output:-

```
['licnep', 'god', 'omem', 'olleH']
```

Comment: Why is it not making a change in the actual list?

Comment: @Kakarot_7, Because in your code, `word` is a local variable and it is required to store it again in the original list or in a new list.

Comment: @Kakarot_7 you are successfully reversing the string but not storing it anywhere hence the change are lost.

Answer (score 1):

You should use another list to save your changes because you should not modify the same list which you are looping over. 
So you can fix your code like this:

```
mylist  = ['pencil', 'dog', 'memo', 'Hello']
new_list = []

for word in mylist:
    word = word[::-1]
    new_list.append(word)

print(new_list)
```

Another way to reach the same goal is to use list comprehension. 
Also in this case you are basically created a new list like this:

```
mylist  = ['pencil', 'dog', 'memo', 'Hello']
newlist = [word[::-1] for word in mylist]

print(new_list)
```

Comment: But i did change the original list by `word = word[::-1]`. Why isn't the change reflected in the original list ?

Comment: Because you are assigning the new value to "word" that is the value of the list element in the for loop, but it is not enough to change the list.

Answer (score 1):

The problem with your `code` is that you are changing the word but not storing it in current list. You can use following script, if you want change in current list

```
mylist  = ['pencil', 'dog', 'memo', 'Hello']

for word in range(len(mylist)):
    mylist[word] = mylist[word][::-1]
print(mylist)
```

Output

```
['licnep', 'god', 'omem', 'olleH']
```